# Why doesn't a formset provide values like a form in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-1.5

When I create a form like this:

```
class IPTCForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = IPTC
    fields = ['creator', 'datetime_value', 'headline', 'caption', 'instructions']

[...]

form = IPTCForm(instance=iptcObj)
```

The form already is populated with values from the object.

But when I use it in a formset instead, all the values are gone:

```
IPTCFormSet = formset_factory(IPTCForm)
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in a query set:

```
IPTCFormSet = modelformset_factory(IPTCForm)
formset = IPTCFormSet(queryset=IPTC.objects.all())
```

Comment: That gives me: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'

Comment: Ah sorry, you need to use `modelformset_factory` if you are building this from a model. Similar to `ModelForm`. I have edited my answer to show that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm a bit confused now. Actually my idea was to use the formset so I could combine the IPTCForm with another ModelForm. Then the user should be able to edit both or just one of the two forms. Is it right to use a formset in that case?

Comment: No. A formset is for editing multiple instances of one model. (And adding new instances.) If you have 2 separate `ModelForm`s you want to edit, you could just print both forms in your template between one `<form></form>` tag. You might need to do some extra work to skip validation on one of the forms if all the fields are empty.